# pySimpleGUI - Set Cursor and refresh

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Using pySimpleGUI I simply want to change the mouse cursor while the code is processing a query, but the cursor does only change *after* the code is executed... it does work when I put a window.read() after the set_cursor() call, but then the proceeding code is not executed immediately. What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, the documentation does not provide an example.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#... more code   
window = sg.Window(f"Report Generator v{APP_VERSION}", layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        # close button was clicked
        if event == "Close" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        # Generate button was clicked
        elif event == "Generate":
            window.set_cursor("coffee_mug")
            window.refresh()

            # more code where the cursor should be changed but isn't
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure why is that, but the following works as desired. The crucial part is to add the Submit button ID at the `window['Submit'].set_cursor("coffee_mug")`, then the new cursor is displayed before the next code is executed. And it will also show the new cursor at the entire window, not only when hovering over the button as one might have expected:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Hello World")],
    [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
]

window = sg.Window(f"Report Generator v{APP_VERSION}", layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        # close button was clicked
        if event == "Close" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        # Generate button was clicked
        elif event == "Submit":
            window['Submit'].set_cursor("coffee_mug")
            time.sleep(5)

            # more code where the cursor should be changed but isn't
```

Comment: There's no event "Generate" in your code, it should be "Submit". After Button "Submit" clicked, new cursor will be shown only when hovering this button.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is due to the code I cut away for this example, I will correct this. But it is not relevant for the issue itself.

Answer (score 0):

Following code work on my WIN10

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Hello World")],
    [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
]
window = sg.Window(f"Title", layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
            break

        elif event == "Submit":
            window.set_cursor("coffee_mug")

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your post. Did you also try something like adding a time.sleep(10) after the set_cursor function? Does it still change the cursor right after you click Submit?

Comment: ...it does not on my PC

Comment: The GUI will have no response for 10 seconds if you add statement `time.sleep(10)` after `window.set_cursor("coffee_mug")`. After 10 seconds passed, cursor changed and it still work.

Comment: That is exactly the point, the cursor should change *before* the time.sleep()

Comment: IMO, the cursor changed and displayed on the GUI, but the GUI is not respond when time.sleep, so no action for GUI to show the new cursor. Most of time, don't use time.sleep in the GUI main thread, try to use it in other thread.

Comment: Jason, the time.sleep() was only a placeholder for other code that takes some seconds to execute, and the idea was to show the user that there is actually code executing by changing the cursor while the code needs to calculate. Sorry if this did not became clear by the question.

Comment: It is same as time.sleep if your code takes some seconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I have a window that connects to a database and I disable the button and change the button text to show that it is "Working".  When the task is finished I enable the button and change the text back to "Connect to Database".  I think this is very similar to what you are trying to do.

Here is my function:

```
def dbConnectWin(iniConfig, user='', winTitle='Database User Name', pwd=''):
        sg.theme(iniConfig.read('MasterWin', 'window-theme'))
        layout = [[sg.Text('User:', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText(user, key='User', size=(30, 1))],
                  [sg.Text('Password:', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText(pwd, key='Password', password_char='*', size=(30, 1))],
                  [sg.Radio('Local Lan', "Host", default=True, key='LanHost'),
                   sg.Radio('VPN-ing', "Host", key='VPNHost'),  
                   sg.Radio('Wan or Remote', "Host", key='WanHost')], 
                  [sg.Button(button_text='Connect to Database', key='ConnectButton', bind_return_key=True),  
                   sg.Button('Exit Program', key='Cancel')]]  
        window = sg.Window(winTitle, layout, element_justification='center',
                           location=iniConfig.read('MasterWin', 'window-position'), icon=dataBaseIcon, finalize=True, keep_on_top=True)
        window.force_focus()
        window.bring_to_front()
        window['ConnectButton'].set_focus()
        while True:
            event, values = window.read(timeout=50)
            if event != '__TIMEOUT__':
                print("DBlogin Event", event)
            if event == 'ConnectButton':
                if values['LanHost']:
                    host = iniConfig.read('GLOBAL', 'lan-host-name')
                elif values['WanHost']:
                    host = iniConfig.read('GLOBAL', 'wan-host-name')
                elif values['VPNHost']:
                    host = iniConfig.read('GLOBAL', 'vpn-host-name')
                else:
                    sg.popup("Program Error - Lan & Wan Host was False", location=centerChildWindow(window),
                             title="Program Error", keep_on_top=True, modal=True, auto_close=True)
                    sys.exit(1)
                window['ConnectButton'].update(disabled=True, text='Working')
                window.refresh()
                con = databaseConnect("Database", values['User'], values['Password'], host, window)
                if con != -1:
                    window['ConnectButton'].update(disabled=True, text='Connected')
                    window.refresh()
                    break
                else:
                    window['ConnectButton'].update(disabled=False, text='Connect to Database')
                    window.refresh()
            elif event in ('Cancel', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
                sys.exit(1)
        window.close()
        del window
        iniConfig.dbUser = values['User']  # set global variable dbUser of the user that validated loging into database
        iniConfig.conDB = con
        return
```